# Display a Leaflet Heatmap with a gpx file and Omnivore

Tags: leaflet, heat-map, gpx, leaflet-plugins

I first displayed a Leaflet Heatmap with the plugin : "leaflet-heat.js" and a geojson file with this code found on Gis.Stackexchange

```
var geoJsonUrl = "link to the geojson file"

    var geojsonLayer = $.ajax({
    url : geoJsonUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    });

geoJson2heat = function(geojson, intensity) {
        return geojson.features.map(function(feature) {
        return [parseFloat(feature.geometry.coordinates[1]), 
                parseFloat(feature.geometry.coordinates[0]), intensity];
        });
        };
    
$.when(geojsonLayer).done(function() {
        var punti_mappa = geoJson2heat(geojsonLayer.responseJSON, 4);
        var heatMap = L.heatLayer(punti_mappa,{ 
        minOpacity: 0.9,
        radius: 7,
        gradient: {
        0.02: 'blue',
        0.2: 'cyan',
        0.3: 'green',
        0.6: 'yellow',
        0.7: 'red'
    },
    blur: 15, 
        maxZoom: 13});
        map.addLayer(heatMap);
        });
```

Now I want to display a Leaflet Heatmap with a gpx file and the "omnivore.js" plugin. I displayed the points (markers) on the map with this code

```
var gpxUrl = "link gpx file"
var gpxlayer = omnivore.gpx(gpxUrl).addTo(map);
```

but I don't know how to adapt the rest with the url to display the heatmap ?

```
var geojsonLayer = $.ajax({
    url : ?
    dataType : 'json',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the `'ready'` event of `omnivore.gpx` call and then use `.toGeoJSON` method to get GeoJSON object from your `gpxlayer`. This you can than use as input to `geoJson2heat` call.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var gpxlayer = omnivore.gpx(gpxUrl)
  .on('ready', function() {
      var geoJSON = gpxlayer.toGeoJSON();
      var punti_mappa = geoJson2heat(geoJSON, 4);
      .
      .
      .
    })
  .addTo(map);
```